# CakePHP and Set::combine

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I need to get the data for each language in it's field as an array.
Probably the best approach in CakePHP will be `Set::combine` but can't get it working.
I can do it manually with `foreach` but I don't think that will be the best way.

Here is the example:

```
Array
    (
        [Article] => Array
            (
                [id] => 131
                [title] => TEST
            )

        [titleTranslation] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 62
                        [locale] => eng
                        [model] => Article
                        [foreign_key] => 131
                        [field] => title
                        [content] => TEST
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 63
                        [locale] => fre
                        [model] => Article
                        [foreign_key] => 131
                        [field] => title
                        [content] => Salva
                    )
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 64
                        [locale] => rus
                        [model] => Article
                        [foreign_key] => 131
                        [field] => title
                        [content] => Пвет
                    )
            )
    )
```

into this array:

```
Array
    (
        [Article] => Array
            (
                [id] => 131
                [title] =>  Array
                    (
                        [eng] => TEST
                        [fre] => Salva
                        [rus] => Пвет
                    )
            )

        .... the rest is not important

    )
```

**Solved-----**

```
            $translatedData = Set::combine($this->data['titleTranslation'], '{n}.locale', '{n}.content', '{n}.field');
            $this->data['Article'] = array_merge($this->data['Article'], $translatedData);
```

Comment: Kindly write a select query so that peers can help you in a bit fast manner.

Comment: Try `$title = Set::combine($article['titleTranslation'], '{n}.locale', '{n}.content'); $article['Article']['title'] = $title;` Set has become deprecated in later version of 2.0, though. Hash is the replacement.